# Get N th row value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
      DECLARE @ActionNumber varchar(20)='EHPL-DES-SQ-1021'
         set @ActionNumber=(select top 1 * from dbo.ANOSplit(@ActionNumber,'-')
         order by ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  items))
         select @ActionNumber
```

from above query i need to return the `2ND` and `3RD` index from initial `@ActionNumber`
'**`EHPL-DES-SQ-1021`**' after `Split()`.

format of the ActionNumber is exactly as above but **DES**, **SQ** and **1021** can change.

so i can not use ORDER BY  items ASC or ORDER BY  items DESC because it will order alphabetically.

above query returns 'EHPL'.how can i get DES and SQ.

Comment: what is `items` in your query?

Comment: item is values return by split function ANOSplit in this case it's 1021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the `ANOSplit` function, but I would insert the result into a temp table or table variable.
As you said yourself, you can't just `ORDER BY` the values returned by the `ANOSplit` function because it will order alphabetically.
--> So you can use a temp table with an `IDENTITY` column, and use this for sorting:

```
DECLARE @ActionNumber varchar(20)='EHPL-DES-SQ-1021'

declare @tmp table
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    item varchar(20)
)

insert into @tmp (item)
select * from dbo.ANOSplit(@ActionNumber,'-')

select * from @tmp where id in (2,3)
```

The items will be inserted into the table in the exact order returned by the function, so after inserting you know that the lines with `id` 2 and 3 are the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Substring` with `CharIndex` >>>

```
DECLARE @ActionNumber varchar(20)='EHPL-DES-SQ-1021'
select SUBSTRING (@ActionNumber,CHARINDEX ('-',@ActionNumber,0) + 1, 3)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score -1):

This isn't tested, but I think it will work:

```
DECLARE @ActionNumber varchar(20)='EHPL-DES-SQ-1021'
WITH nCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  items) AS RNum

    FROM dbo.ANOSplit(@ActionNumber,'-')
)
SELECT * FROM nCTE WHERE RNum = 2   --put n here
```